# Recursive descent parsing: high precedence unary operators

Tags: parsing, recursive-descent

I've figured out how to implement binary operators with precedence, like this (pseudocode):

```
method plus
   times()

   while(consume(plus_t)) do
       times()
   end
end

method times
   number()

   while(consume(times_t))
       number()
   end
end

// plus() is the root operation

// omitted: number() consumes a number token
```

So when I parse `4 + 5 * 6` it would:

1. plus

   1. multiply

      1. number (4 consumed)
   2. plus_t consumed
   3. multiply

      1. number (5 consumed)
      2. times_t consumed
      3. number (6 consumed)

However, when I try adding a `minus` method (prefix minusing like `-4`, not infix minusing like `4 - 5`):

```
method minus
    consume(minus_t)
    plus()
end
```

It takes a very low precedence, so `-4 + 5` becomes `-(4 + 5)` rather than `(-4) + 5` and this is undesirable.

What can I do to make a high precedence unary operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not said where in the hierarchy you're adding the `minus` method, but it looks like you're adding it above `plus` and making it the root.

You need to put it at last if you want `unary -` to have a higher precedence than `+` and `*`.

In your pseudocode, something like this should work:

```
method times
   minus()

   while(consume(times_t))
       minus()
   end
end

method minus
    if(consume(minus_t))
      // next number should have a unary minus attached
      number()
    else
      number()
    end
end
```

I'm learning about parsers these days, so I wrote a complete parser based on your pseudocode, it's in LiveScript, but should be easy to follow.

Edit: Running example on jsfiddle.net - http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/7Pmwc/

```
parse = (string) ->
  index = 0

  is-digit = (d) -> '0' <= d <= '9'

  plus = ->
    str = times()
    while consume "+"
      str = "(+ #{str} #{times()})"
    str

  times = ->
    str = unary-minus()
    while consume "*"
      str = "(* #{str} #{unary-minus()})"
    str

  unary-minus = ->
    if consume "-"
      "(- #{number()})"
    else
      number()

  number = ->
    if is-digit peek()
      ret = peek()
      advance()
      while is-digit peek()
        ret += peek()
        advance()
      ret
    else
      throw "expected number at index = #{index}, got #{peek()}"

  peek = ->
    string[index]

  advance = ->
    index++

  consume = (what) ->
    if peek() == what
      advance()
      true

  plus()


console.log parse "4+5*6"
console.log parse "-4+5"
console.log parse "-4*-5+-4"
```

Output:

```
(+ 4 (* 5 6))
(+ (- 4) 5)
(+ (* (- 4) (- 5)) (- 4))
```

PS: you may want to look at [Operator-precedence Parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser) for parsing complex precedence/associativity relatively easily.